# Neo won't start with remote access turned on after upgrading to 3.0.0

Tags: neo4j

I've upgraded to Neo4j Community Edition 3.0.0 on a Windows server. The database upgraded fine and all looks OK on the server.

The firewall settings are same as before, port 7474 open.

When I uncommented this...

> # To have HTTP accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
>   dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:#{default.http.port}

... the database won't start, it gives me the 'In just a few seconds Neo will be ready' message but never actually starts.

Remote access was enabled previously on the same database.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: OK, so this should be:-

dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474

(obviously)

Answer (score 2):

I got my instance of neo4j running by modifying the config to be

```
dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474
```

Comment: In later versions this seems to of changed to `dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474`